# How to run Linux package.json script in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

My `package.json` contains this: `"build": "sh -ac '. ./.env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts-avis build'",`. I want to run this won my Windows machine though. How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script runs a subshell, sources a given envfile to activate the configuration therein, then runs `react-scripts-avis build`.

An equivalent for non-Posix shells could be to use [`env-cmd`](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd), á la

```
./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./.env.SOMETHING node ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts-avis build
```

NB: I haven't tried `env-cmd` personally, it just comes [recommended by `cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).